# Verify that x,y is a joint probability density function for X and Y

Tags: integration, probability-distributions

Given the function $f_x,_y$ = $\lbrace 24xy, 0\leq x,y \leq 1, 0\leq x+y\leq 1$

I need to verify that this function is indeed the joint pdf for X and Y. 
I know that to do that I need to check if:

$\int_x\int_y 24xy$  $dydx$ = $1$

However I'm unsure about the limits for both integrals . Would they just be $[1,0]$ for both x and y since $0\leq x,y\leq 1$ or would it be something else since $ 0\leq x+y\leq 1$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should integrate over the triangle $0\leq x+y\leq 1$.

So if you let $x$ in outer integral to be any number $0\leq x \leq 1$, the variable $y$ in the inner integral should be $0\leq y\leq 1-x$.

$$
\int_{x=0}^{x=1} \int_{y=0}^{y=1-x} f(x,y) \,dy \,dx. 
$$